# Difference between arrays and lists towards collection changes in linq

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, collections

I found behavior in the interaction between linq and collections, that I can't understand.

I was taught, that changing collection during enumeration through this collection leads to InvalidOperationException.

But that's a bit more complex.

I have an example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PwgoOO) ([mirror](https://pastebin.com/nP1LeSB3))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 

public class Program
{
        public void Main()
        {
            Program.Try(Program.HandleArray_Where, "array.where");
            Program.Try(Program.HandleArray_Where_OrderBy, "array.where.orderby");
            Program.Try(Program.HandleList_Where, "list.where");
            Program.Try(Program.HandleList_Where_OrderBy, "list.where.orderby");
        }

        private static void Try(Action action, string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);

            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void HandleArray_Where()
        {
            IList<int> arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var enumerable = arr.Where(item => item > 2);

            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                arr[3] = 0;

                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        private static void HandleArray_Where_OrderBy()
        {
            IList<int> arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var orderedEnumerable = arr.Where(item => item > 2).OrderBy(asd => asd);

            foreach (var item in orderedEnumerable)
            {
                arr[3] = 0;

                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        private static void HandleList_Where()
        {
            IList<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var enumerable = list.Where(item => item > 2);

            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                list[3] = 0;

                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        private static void HandleList_Where_OrderBy()
        {
            IList<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var orderedEnumerable = list.Where(item => item > 2).OrderBy(asd => asd);

            foreach (var item in orderedEnumerable)
            {
                list[3] = 0;

                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
}
```

There are four collections, and I'm trying to change them during enumeration. I was expected to have InvalidOperationException four times, but I had it once only.

Output:

```
array.where
3
5


array.where.orderby
3
4
5


list.where
3
Invalid operation


list.where.orderby
3
4
5
```

So, I can interpret the results like this:

`.OrderBy()` works with the result of `.Where()`, with a new collection, that doesn't feel changes in the original one, because the sample was taken before changes. So in blocks "array.where.orderby" and "list.where.orderby" there are three numbers.

But I don't understand the behavior of "array.where" and "list.where" blocks. Why I can change `int[]` and can't change `List<int>` during iterations, especially if both of them are converted to `IList<int>`? Now I'm looking at this as a discrepancy with Liskov substitution principle: one parent type has two different behaviors depending on the true type of the variable

Comment: No, there is no violation of the LSP. You just made a false assumption. According to the MSDN docmentation for `IList<T>.GetEnumerator` / `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`: _"An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its **behavior is undefined**."_

Comment: @elgonzo, thank you, I believe you're right. I was confused by docs to the [IEnumerator Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx). It told us that Exception has to be thrown. But [IEnumerable.GetEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) truly told about undefined behavior.